# How to convert this Sql to Linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How would I write this sql as a C# Linq to Sql statement?

```
DECLARE @RET DATETIME

SET @RET = (SELECT MAX(EffectiveDate)
            FROM Material_Price
            WHERE Material_ID = @MatID
            AND EffectiveDate <= GetDate())
```

(It just isn't coming to me tonight)

Answer (score 1):

```
var time = db.Material_Price.Where(m => m.Material_ID == MatID
                                        && m.EffectiveDate <= DateTime.Today)
                            .Max(m => m.EffectiveDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to do something like this:

```
var time = db
    .Material_Price
        .Where(m => m.Material_ID == MatID)
        .Where(m => m.EffectiveDate <= DateTime.Today)
        .OrderByDescending(m => m.EffectiveDate)
        .First();
```